# Create a pivot table from two tables based on dates

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, dao

I have two MS Access tables sharing a one to many relationship. Their structures are like the following:

**tbl_Persons**

```
+----------+------------+-----------+
| PersonID | PersonName | OtherData |
+----------+------------+-----------+
|    1     |  PersonA   |    etc.   |
|    2     |  PersonB   |           |
|    3     |  PersonC   |           |
```

**tbl_Visits**

```
+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------
| VisitID  |  PersonID  |  VisitDate | dozens of other fields
+----------+------------+------------+-----------
|    1     |     1      |  09/01/13  |
|    2     |     1      |  09/02/13  |
|    3     |     2      |  09/03/13  |
|    4     |     2      |  09/04/13  |  etc...
```

I wish to create a new table based on the `VisitDate` field, the column headings of which are Visit-*n* where *n* is 1 to the number of visits, Visit-*n*-Data1, Visit-*n*-Data2, Visit-*n*-Data3 etc.

**MergedTable**

```
+----------+----------+---------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+
| PersonID |  Visit1  |  Visit1Data1  |  Visit1Data2... |  Visit2  | Visit2Data1... |
+----------+----------+---------------+-----------
|    1     | 09/01/13 |               |                 | 09/02/13 |
|    2     | 09/03/13 |               |                 | 09/04/13 |   
|    3     |  etc.    |               |
```

I am really not sure how to do this. Whether SQL query or using DAO then looping through records and columns. It is essential that there is only 1 `PersonID` per row and all his data appears chronologically into columns.

Answer (score 0):

Start of by ranking the visits with something like

```
SELECT PersonID, VisitID, 
(SELECT COUNT(VisitID) FROM tbl_Visits AS C 
WHERE C.PersonID = tbl_Visits.PersonID 
AND C.VisitDate < tbl_Visits.VisitDate) AS RankNumber 
FROM tbl_Visits
```

Use this query as a base for the 'pivot'

Since you seem to have some visits of persons on the same day (visit 1 and 2) the WHERE clause needs to be a bit more sophisticated. But I hope you get the basic concept.

Pivoting can be done with multiple LEFT JOINs.
I question if my solution will have a high performance, since I did not test it. It is easier in SQL Server than in MS Access to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you, @Wietze314. I really don't know much about SQL (and I will try to learn it). I have made a way around this problem using VBA. Code appears in a separate post I made. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18651668/recordset-edits-and-updates-the-wrong-record